# updating log4j2 to 2.15.0 breaks cxf wsdl2java

Tags: log4j2, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am updating log4j2 from 2.14.1 to 2.15.0 in a maven project that uses cxf's wsdl2java (version 3.4.5). Updating causes the pipeline to break with the following exception during the generate-sources phase:

```
[WARNING] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContextFactory.isClassLoaderDependent()'
[WARNING]   at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:48)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
[WARNING]   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.<init>(RuntimeInstance.java:121)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.<clinit>(RuntimeSingleton.java:79)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:102)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.initVelocity(VelocityGenerator.java:87)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.<init>(VelocityGenerator.java:53)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.AbstractGenerator.<init>(AbstractGenerator.java:47)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AbstractJAXWSGenerator.<init>(AbstractJAXWSGenerator.java:30)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AntGenerator.<init>(AntGenerator.java:44)
[WARNING]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[WARNING]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[WARNING]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[WARNING]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[WARNING]   at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndGenerators(PluginLoader.java:270)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndProfile(PluginLoader.java:385)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.loadFrontEnd(WSDLToJava.java:64)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:96)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
[WARNING]   at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.ForkOnceWSDL2Java.main(ForkOnceWSDL2Java.java:51)
```

Any hints on where to look further?

Comment: It seems you didn't upgrade everything to `2.15.0`: your `log4j-api` is still at a lower version than `2.15.0`.

Comment: You're right, @PiotrP.Karwasz, I had to set the log4j2 version for the plugin, too (did it through the dependencyManagement, in the end). Thanks!